# EasyMock: Get real parameter value for EasyMock.anyObject()?

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

In my unit tests I'm using EasyMock for creating mock objects.
In my test code I have something like this

```
EasyMock.expect(mockObject.someMethod(anyObject())).andReturn(1.5);
```

So, now EasyMock will accept any call to `someMethod()`. Is there any way to get real value that is passed to `mockObject.someMethod()`, or I need to write `EasyMock.expect()` statement for all possible cases?

Comment: Where do you want to get the value passed?

Comment: in .andReturn(); method, to return different values for different cases

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `Capture` class to expect and capture parameter value:

```
Capture capturedArgument = new Capture();
EasyMock.expect(mockObject.someMethod(EasyMock.capture(capturedArgument)).andReturn(1.5);

Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, capturedArgument.getValue());
```

Note that `Capture` is generic type and you can parametrize it with an argument class:

```
Capture<Integer> integerArgument = new Capture<Integer>();
```

Update:

If you want to return different values for different arguments in your `expect` definition, you can use `andAnswer` method:

```
EasyMock.expect(mockObject.someMethod(EasyMock.capture(integerArgument)).andAnswer(
    new IAnswer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer answer() {
            return integerArgument.getValue(); // captured value if available at this point
        }
    }
);
```

As pointed in comments, another option is to use `getCurrentArguments()` call inside `answer`:

```
EasyMock.expect(mockObject.someMethod(anyObject()).andAnswer(
    new IAnswer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer answer() {
            return (Integer) EasyMock.getCurrentArguments()[0];
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it is not possible to call capturedArgument.getValue() in andReturn method right? andReturn(capturedArgument.getValue())

Comment: I found it, when I use andAnswer insted of andReturn it is possible to use capturedArgument.getValue() for return value, **Thanks for help***

Comment: inside an andAnswer() you can also call the method getCurrentArguments() which returns an Object[] of all the parameters passed in

Comment: You can also capture elements with a void method through `myObject.myMethod(capture(captureElement));` then `expectLastCall()`

Comment: Calling the `Capture`class constructor is deprecated. Call `EasyMock.newCapture()` instead.